# sed append text after match

Tags: sed, append

I am writing a shell script to be able to append text after the match is found in a file

for example, in ~/.bash_profile file for the following line

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin
```

we need to append it with :/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_38/bin

so it'll become the following

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_38/bin
```

how could I do it with sed?

I tried with the following command from inside the console first, but it gave me error complaining 'sed: -e expression #1, char 13: unknown option to `s''

```
sed '/PATH/s/$/:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_38/bin' ~/.bash_profile
```

what's wrong with my command above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you have regex delimiters in the replacement part of the substitute command. Either escape them with `\` or use a different delimiter (comma in this case):

```
sed '/PATH/ s,$,:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_38/bin,' ~/.bash_profile
```

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's|PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin|&:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_38/bin|' ~/.bash_profile
```